# puppeteer - How I can close browser after page throw some error?

Tags: puppeteer

How do I close the browser with puppeteer when the page throws an error?

```
async function fnGoogle(page) {
  try {
    //some code here
    await page.goto('blablalba');
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`browser.close()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/38f112f/docs/api.md#browserclose) to close the browser, but you'd have to do it *before* re-throwing the error in your `catch`-block:

```
} catch (e) {
  await browser.close()
  throw e
}
```

[demo](https://puppeteersandbox.com/oSOj4wes)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can I close the browser after throw error?

Comment: In your example, you'd have to close the browser before re-throwing the error from the page.